# Error org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, jsp, custom-tags

I have tried to make a simple custom tag JSP application, bu talternatively I keep receiving this error, or sometimes `Unable to load tag handler class "HelloTag" for tag "ex:Hello".`
My `index.jsp` looks like this:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

<%@taglib prefix="ex" uri="WEB-INF/custom.tld"%>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>customised tag</title>
</head>
<body>
<ex:Hello/>
</body>
</html>
```

My `custom.tld` from WEB-INF looks like this:

```
<taglib>
   <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
   <jsp-version>2.0</jsp-version>
   <short-name>Example TLD</short-name>

   <tag>
      <name>Hello</name>
      <tag-class>HelloTag</tag-class>
      <body-content>empty</body-content>

   </tag>
</taglib>
```

And this is the Java class `HelloTag.java` from WEB-INF/classes:

```
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.*;
import javax.servlet.jsp.*;
import java.io.*;


public class HelloTag extends SimpleTagSupport {
   public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {
      JspWriter out = getJspContext().getOut();
      out.write("Hello Custom Tag!");
   }
}
```

The entire error log:

```
exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.labJavaIJ.web.index_jsp
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:177)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:376)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.labJavaIJ.web.index_jsp
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:132)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:172)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:376)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: Error says everything, your jasper api is not present in your classpath.

Comment: @AmitBhati I still have the problem, even if I add it to the classpath

Comment: Check your servlet container i.e. Tomcat if it has different version of your jasper api. In case, if same api with different versions is present in your classpath, you will receive this error.